# Vxworks getting stuck in memory routines

Tags: malloc, semaphore, vxworks

I'm running vxWorks 6.3 and have run into a problem.  I have a series of tasks running as in an RTP. I create a task, do stuff then destroy the task. Then create two tasks, very close together, do some stuff and destroy them.  These tasks have to do crazy things like, malloc and free memory.  Unfortunately, if I do this enough times, one of the tasks will get stuck in the memory (both malloc and free) routines on a semaphore.  It's always the second task that gets "lost" at the very start of the task in either free or malloc.  After the failure, I can still create tasks and I can still malloc memory.  The failing task sits forever, waiting for the semaphore... A semaphore that other tasks MUST be using.

Does anyone have any idea how a task can get stuck in the memory routines?

```
0x08265e58 malloc       +0x2c : 0x082416f4 ()
0x08267e50 memPartAlloc +0x28 : 0x08241734 ()
0x08267e0c memPartAlignedAlloc+0x70 : 0x08267c04 ()
0x08267c7c memPartFree  +0xfc : 0x08240654 ()
0x082753c0 semTake      +0x90 : 0x08242534 ()
0x082752ec semUMTake    +0xd8 : 0x08242514 ()
---- system call boundary ----

-> tw 0x69d21b0
  NAME       ENTRY       TID       STATUS   DELAY  OBJ_TYPE    OBJ_ID   OBJ_NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ---------- ---------- --------
tHttp631-2  0x827dbfc  0x69d21b0 PEND           0 SEM_M       0x6859650 N/A

Semaphore Id        : 0x6859650
Semaphore Type      : MUTEX
Task Queuing        : PRIORITY
Pended Tasks        : 1
Owner               : 0x69d1a08    Deleted!
Options             : 0xd       SEM_Q_PRIORITY
                                SEM_DELETE_SAFE
                                SEM_INVERSION_SAFE
VxWorks Events
--------------
Registered Task     : NONE
Event(s) to Send    : N/A
Options             : N/A
Pended Tasks
------------
   NAME      TID    PRI TIMEOUT
---------- -------- --- -------
tHttp631-25502 69d21b0 120       0
value = 0 = 0x0
->
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you allocate enough memory for the worst case at init time, and then just re-use that memory throughout the duration of your program. Especially if you actually have real time requirements as malloc/free are non-deterministic operations, I also recommend re-using the tasks rather that recreating new tasks at runtime, then use a semaphore or msgQueue to kick off the appropriate tasks at the appropriate times. So your program flow might look something like this:

```
initTime()
{
    t1mem = malloc(t1memSize);
    t2mem = malloc(t2memSize);
    t3mem = malloc(t3memSize);
    t1q = msgQCreate(qlen, msglen, MSG_Q_FIFO);
    t2q = msgQCreate(qlen, msglen, MSG_Q_FIFO);
    t3q = msgQCreate(qlen, msglen, MSG_Q_FIFO);
    rspq = msgQCreate(qlen, msglen, MSG_Q_FIFO);
    taskSpawn("t1", t1pri, ..., t1Entry, t1mem, t1q, rspq, ...);
    taskSpawn("t2", t2pri, ..., t2Entry, t2mem, t2q, rspq, ...);
    taskSpawn("t3", t3pri, ..., t3Entry, t3mem, t3q, rspq, ...);

    runTime(t1sem, t2sem, t3sem, rspq);

    msgQDelete(t1q);
    msgQDelete(t2q);
    msgQDelete(t3q);
    msgQDelete(rspq);
    free(t1mem);
    free(t2mem);
    free(t3mem);
}

runTime(MSG_Q_ID t1q, MSG_Q_ID t2q, MSG_Q_ID t3q, MSG_Q_ID rspq)
{
    while (programRun)
    {
        tasksDone = 0;
        msgQSend(t1q, t1start, msglen, 100, MSG_PRI_NORMAL);
        if (msgQReceive(rspq, buf, msglen, errorCaseTimeout) == OK)
        {
            // check to make sure the msg is t1done... 
            // report error if it isn't...
            msgQSend(t2q, t2start, msglen, 100, MSG_PRI_NORMAL);
            msgQSend(t3q, t3start, msglen, 100, MSG_PRI_NORMAL);
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
            {
                if (msgQReceive(rspq, buf, msglen, errorCaseTimeout) == OK)
                {
                     // check to make sure the msg is t2done/t3done... 
                     // report error if it isn't...
                     tasksDone++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (tasksDone == 2)
        {
             // everything is good... keep on running...
        }
        else
        {
             // a task didnt finish within the errorCaseTimeout time...
             // report error or something, maybe set programRun to false... 
        }
    }
}

t1Entry(void* mem, MSG_Q_ID q, MSG_Q_ID rspq)
{
    while (programRun)
    {
        if (msgQReceive(q, buf, msglen, 100) == OK)
        {
            doTask1(mem);
            msgQSend(rspq, t1done, msglen, 100, MSG_PRI_NORMAL);
        }
    }
}

t2Entry(void* mem, MSG_Q_ID q, MSG_Q_ID rspq)
{
    while (programRun)
    {
        if (msgQReceive(q, buf, msglen, 100) == OK)
        {
            doTask2(mem);
            msgQSend(rspq, t2done, msglen, 100, MSG_PRI_NORMAL);
        }
    }
}

t3Entry(void* mem, MSG_Q_ID q, MSG_Q_ID rspq)
{
    while (programRun)
    {
        if (msgQReceive(q, buf, msglen, 100) == OK)
        {
            doTask3(mem);
            msgQSend(rspq, t3done, msglen, 100, MSG_PRI_NORMAL);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously the above code is not very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and not all error cases are fully handled, but it is a start and has a good chance of working deterministically.

Comment: When we get in the failure state, we have 19meg free (and require nowhere near that), so I'm sure we are not running out of memory. If it were a simple "out of memory" I should get a msg on the console, which I am not getting. Yes, my next attempt at a work around was going to just this.  I was going to have two threads that I could re-use.  I have tried a couple of other work arounds but this just seems to move the problem somewhere else.  I was hoping to find the root cause of the problem so that I could say with some certainty that my final solution was not just masking the real problem.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't suggesting that you were running out of memory, rather I was suggesting a different approach that uses principles that are more common in real time/embedded systems. Indeed you are correct if there is a problem this approach may hide it.

Comment: I also just noticed the following in the output above: Owner               : 0x69d1a08    Deleted! Sadly I no longer have access to a vxworks system, source, or docs. But that raises a concern, if the owner of the mutex was deleted, then it can never give the semaphore, thus your pending thread (0x69d21b0) will block forever.

Comment: Hi Chris,  Thanks for the suggests.  Changing the code is my mission today.  I also noticed that the "owner" was deleted.  I think this refers to the task that created the sem, rather than the task that is holding the sem.  I can still successfully access the memory pool after the failure so I'm pretty sure that the semaphore is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions:

- Are all the tasks created/deleted in an RTP?
- How are you "destroying the task"?
- When then task blocks, are new malloc/tasks creation in the same RTP or different RTP?
- Are you deleting entire RTPs?

It sounds like you are using a taskDelete from one task to destroy those other tasks.  If that's the case, then it is possible that a task is being deleted in the middle of a memory operation.

Since this is a malloc operation in an RTP, each RTP created contains it's own heap (malloc) semaphore.  I would think this would be the semaphore being held.

I would suggest contacting Wind River support.  This might be an issue they are familiar with.

Comment: No, we are not using taskDelete.  The tasks finish their duty and return from the calling function. All the tasks involved are in the same RTP process. The RTP continues to run; it is does not exit.  I wish I had the option of contacting WindRiver, but we terminated our support contract years ago.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a problem I am having, although I am seeing a different symptom. 
In both cases the owner of a semaphore is being deleted. In my case, I am having the tWebTask hang and tracing that to a missing semaphore owner on a web socket.

[Here's the link to my SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014836/twebtask-is-hanging-semaphore-owner-is-missing).